# Discard the decorator

Tags: python

Could you help me understand whether it is possible to use a function both with a decorator and without it.

Example:

```
def makeitalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return wrapped

@makeitalic
def hello():
    return "hello, sir or madam!"
```

The only way that comes to my mind:

```
def hello():
    return "hello, sir or madam!"

@makeitalic
def italic_hello():
    return(hello())
```

Well, is it possible to use hello() without the decorator?

Comment: Note that `italic_hello = makeitalic(hello)` would be simpler - that's basically what the syntactic sugar of `@makeitalic` is doing anyway.

Comment: You could assign the actual function as an attribute to `wrapped`.

Comment: If you need that kind of dynamic behaviour, don't use decorators.

Comment: I'll expand on this a little since I think the dupe addresses the details but not the bigger picture. The purpose of the decorator is to express a 'static', source-level composition. If you what you have in mind is some kind of runtime, dynamic composition which can be done, undone, modified, etc, a decorator is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general.  The decorated function *replaces* the original, so there is no way to get the original unless the decorator itself makes it available explicitly (e.g., by storing it in some global registry or as an attribute on some object).  (You can access it as a cell variable in the decorated function's closure object, but that's not very robust and shouldn't be relied on except for testing and experimenting.)